# Problema ao inserir na tabela mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, inserir

Boa tarde, tenho este código:

```
<?php 
$servername = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$name = $_POST['DescricaoProd'];
$unid = $_POST['DescricaoUnid'];  

$sql = "INSERT INTO ProdHigiene (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

$conn->close();
?>
```

O meu problema é que sempre que abro a página no menu onde tenho este código ele insere uma linha em branco na tabela do mysql e não devia porque ainda nem criei o formulário.

Alguém consegue ajudar?

Comment: Faça um tour pelo site, começando por https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar o insert enquanto não há formulário a ser submetido, coloque seu código dentro de uma condição `if`

```
//isset — Informa se a variável foi iniciada
//!empty se a variável não é vazia

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && (!empty($_POST['submit']))) {
    $servername = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    $username = "xxxxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxxxxx";
    $dbname = "xxxxxxx";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $conn->set_charset('utf8');

    $name = $_POST['DescricaoProd'];
    $unid = $_POST['DescricaoUnid'];  

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ProdHigiene (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
    VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    $conn->close();
}
```

> Quando houver formulário a ser inserido

```
<form .....>
............
............
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: obrigado....resolveu o meu problema